# Difficulty sourcing a 6mm dc adapter/plug/converter...any ideas?

Tags: dc, adapter

I recently bought [a second power supply for my laptop](https://www.chargers-online.co.uk/330w-dell-3321432-adp330ab-d-ac-power-adapter-charger-cord-p-25878.html). The laptop requires a 330w power supply (it runs a desktop grade CPU), which costs around £120 (Laptop is the Asus GL702ZC).  I managed to source the exact same power supply, except fitted for a different dc port/plug socket for £40, thinking it would be relatively straightforward to find a converter for it, or even a plug that I could solder on to it if need be. It's basically been impossible to find this socket. I visited RS Components in the UK and even they didn't have any of the specific plugs/converters on their database. I was wondering if anyone knows where I should look to find this plug.  I have looked on ebay and ali express,  but no luck either..

The details are:

DC Socket/plug (forgive my ignorance if these are the incorrect naming conventions - this is what it looks like:
[image]

Inside measurement 3.5mm
Outside measurement 6mm

Either a plug with these measurements or a converter for a socket for these measurements converting from:
Inside measurement: 5mm
Outside measurement: 7.4mm

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered cutting the cables and swapping the plug?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is check if your plug has 2 or 3 pins. Most high current laptop plugs use the outside of the cylindrical sleeve for -ve and the inside of the same sleeve for +ve (it looks from your picture that this plug might be one of them). The centre pin is then usually used for IR compensation, or authentication (if you're unlucky enough to have DRM in your PSU).

Most of these connectors are expected to be soldered onto a cable and then have a PVC over- moulded cover and strain-relief applied. So they're not really much use if you want to do it yourself.

Your best bet it to find a connector pre-attached to a length of cable and then join it to your new PSU.

aliexpress, and to some extent ebay, have plenty of hits for "6mm laptop plug".

When you join it either use a premade cable joiner (pretty large and ugly), or solder and heat-shrink. If you use glue lined heatshrink for the outside it should gain some strength.

Bear in mind a laptop may not survive having their input power shorted out, so be careful making your cable. (and obviously check it matches the polarity of the original)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I may have misunderstood where to look, but my plug has one pin in the inside center of the plug (the one in the picture). As for the search on ali express, i'm only getting 4 hits, 2 of which are the cables you described but unfortunately they aren't the right size. But good to know about the cables attached the plug, hadn't thought of trying to source that.

Comment: Try https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC-Power-Male-Tip-Plug-Connector-With-Cord-Cable-For-Samsung-HP-Dell-Sony-Toshiba-Asus/32860997197.html for example. There a lots and lots of sellers selling laptop plugs and cables of various descriptions. Amazon sell pigtails with a juction box attached: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00E49CCL8 . With what did you take the 6mm measurement, calipers?

Comment: Thanks for the links. The measurement was taken with calipers yes